# Does Axios ‘onUploadProgress’ work con react-native?

Tags: react-native, axios

I’m having a problem in which onUploadProgress configuration setting from Axios isn’t being called at all. This is in the context of react native:

```js
const addListing = (listing, onUploadProgress) => {
  // Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryuL67FWkv1CA
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('title', listing.title);
  data.append('price', listing.price);
  data.append('categoryId', listing.category.value);
  data.append('description', listing.description);
  listing.images.forEach((image, index) =>
    data.append('images', {
      name: 'image' + index,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      uri: image,
    })
  );

  if (listing.location)
    data.append('location', JSON.stringify(listing.location));

  return client.post(endpoint, data, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    onUploadProgress: (progress) =>
      onUploadProgress(progress.loaded / progress.total),
  });
};
```

Looking at axios docs https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config it says:

```js
// `onUploadProgress` allows handling of progress events for uploads
  // browser only
  onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
    // Do whatever you want with the native progress event
  },
```

Is it saying that it isn’t supposed to work on react-native (only browsers) ?